# Better way to discover relationship dynamically when saving a new record? (otherSide fails)

Tags: grails, dynamic, grails-orm, one-to-many

Given this relationship:

```
class A {
    String name
    static hasMany = [b:B]
}
class B {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [a:A]
}
```

I have an record b that I want to save.  I've already discovered via working Grails reflection (omitted in the code example below) that it needs to be an instance of class B.  Beyond that, **record b only knows:**

- it has a relation "a"
- relation "a"'s key

Since it's a dynamic case, **we do not know and must discover:**

- relation "a" is to an instance of **class A** (so we can call **A**.find(a's key))
- the "other side" of the relation - class A's perspective - is relation "**b**" (so we can call **.addToB**(b))

So how do I save b to the database?  Here's how I'm doing it:

```
class AssocTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // I don't know this part, but it's in the DB
        def a = new A(name:"al")
        a.save()
    }

    void testAssociation() {
        // I want to create a new B such that name="bob"
        // I also had to discover "class B" using (working) Grails reflection
        // but omitted it for this example.
        def b = new B(name:"bob")
        // ... and the relation is as "given" below
        def given = [a:[name:"al"]]
        // So I need to call A.find([name:"al"]).addToB(b).  But "A" and
        // "addToB" are unknown so need to be found via reflection
        def gdc = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(B)
        given.each { give ->
            def prop = gdc.getPropertyByName(give.key)
            if (prop.isAssociation() && !prop.isOwningSide()) {
                println "I want to use otherSide, but it's ${prop.otherSide}"
                def os = reallyGetOtherSide(B, give)
                def object = os.parent.find(
                        os.parent.newInstance(give.value))
                object."${os.method}"(b)
            }       
        }       
        def bFound = B.findByName("bob")
        assertEquals "al", bFound.a.name
    }

    def reallyGetOtherSide(clazz, relation) {
        def parent=clazz.belongsTo[relation.key] 
        def addTo=parent.hasMany.find { (clazz == it.value) }.key
        [parent:parent, method:"addTo${addTo.capitalize()}"]
    }
}
```

...with otherSide returning null, unfortunately.  This can't be the best way to do this, can it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, You can refer to these docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.3.1%20Saving%20and%20Updating). You can try the following:

```
  `new A(name:"Gatwick")
         .addToB(new B(name:"BA3430"))
         .addToB(new B(name:"EZ0938"))
         .save()`
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding.  This is the dynamic case where I don't know about "A.addToB" and have to discover it by reflection.  Also, I'm not creating a new A.  Imagine I have some other classes and relations I've omitted for brevity.  Thanks for the response, though.